# Raphael.JS: How drag and drop image dom elements in raphael paper

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, raphael

I have html toolbox with set of images. I want to drag and drop them to raphael canvas. Using jquery ui or html5 I guess I can drag and drop, but how make that toolbox html elements (images) raphael objects when it is dropped?

I need function that pass html elem to raphael like this:

```
var r = Raphael(0, 0, 800, 800);

raiseMeWhenDropped(html_elem, e) {
    // create image on canvas area when dropped from toolbox
    r.image(html_elem.src, e.mouseXdropped, e.mouseYdropped, 30, 30);
}
```

Comment: Can you put a test case on a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way would probably be to use HTML drag and drop and make your function the `handler` on `drop` event. You can add the `drop event` to the `canvas` element of your `paper`. Like this for example:

```js
var r = Raphael(0, 60, 800, 800);
var canvas = r.canvas;
var dragImage = document.getElementById('test');

dragImage.addEventListener('dragstart', function (e) {
    dragEvent = e;
});

canvas.addEventListener('dragover', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

canvas.addEventListener('drop', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    r.image(dragEvent.target.src, e.offsetX - dragEvent.offsetX, e.offsetY - dragEvent.offsetY, dragEvent.target.clientWidth, dragEvent.target.clientHeight);
})
```

```css
svg
{
  background-color: #ddd;
}

img
{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>

<img draggable="true" id="test" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a4d924e65b84f1572ea3598437aa5559?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" /><span>You can drop the image on the grey zone</span>
```

Comment: thx! that what I was looking for. can you explain why we use addEventListener('dragover')? I tested If we remove it, nothing will work.

Comment: That's just the way you define a drop target. Since by default most areas on a page are not valid target, by preventing default behavior on drag over you're basically saying that it is a valid drop target. I always found it a bit counterintuitive, but that's how it works. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_operations#droptargets